# Как при клике применить класс в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите как при клике на класс ("img"), выводить определеный класс `info__skills`?

```
class Skills extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { styles: [] };
}

render() {
 return (
  <section className="skills">
    <div className='logo__skills'>
      <div>
        <img src={require("./../img/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.png")} alt=""/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={require("./../img/css3-logo.png")} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={require("./../img/js-logo.png")} alt="" />
      </div>  
    </div >

    <div>
      <div className="info__skills">
        <p>Текст</p>
      </div>
      <div className="info__skills">
      <p>Текст 2 </p>
      </div>
      <div className="info__skills">
      <p>Текст 3 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section >
)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грубый пример того, что Вы хотите. Навешиваем аттрибут на тэг (в моем примере это `div`, а по факту может быть любой другой, `img`, `p`, и прочие), по которому будем кликать, а также обработчик `handleClick`. В стейте сохраняем атррибут элемента, по которому кликнули, в своем примере я использовал `id`. Затем в рендеринге в тернарке проверяем, по какому был клик и выводим тот, который нужно:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      clicked: '',
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.currentTarget;
    this.setState({ clicked: id });
  }

  render() {
    const { clicked } = this.state;
    
    return (
    <div>
      <div id='one' onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p> Image 1 </p>
      </div>
      <div id='two' onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p> Image 2 </p>
      </div>
      <div id='three' onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p> Image 3 </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div className={clicked === "one" ? "info__skills_one" : "no_display"}>
          <p>Текст 1</p>
        </div>
        <div className={clicked === "two" ? "info__skills_two" : "no_display"}>
          <p>Текст 2 </p>
        </div>
        <div className={clicked === "three" ? "info__skills_three" : "no_display"}>
          <p>Текст 3 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.info__skills_one {
  color: red;
}

.info__skills_two {
  color: green;
}

.info__skills_three {
  color: orange;
}

.no_display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Для того, чтобы не юзать тернарки - используйте очень удобную утилиту [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).  Она позволяет использовать классы условно, например вот так:

```
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => ''
```